# How do I install google chrome oin ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

How do I install google chrome on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

open a terminal and follow:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

If you want the 64bit version just replace `i386` with `amd64`

If you encounter any errors simply use

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

To run it from terminal use `google-chrome` or hit the super key and search `Google` or `Chrome`

or  https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/